# Double Integration: $\iint_D\ e^{30x}\ dA$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

I am having trouble with this double integral. I know I must set it up to have the $y$ values go from $x$ to $x+1$ and the $x$ values from $0$ to $1$. When I solved the integral I got the answer $\dfrac1{30}(e^{30}-1)$. Is there anywhere I am making a mistake? Or have I set the integral up incorrectly? Any steps or answers would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: What were the bounds you used in the integration?

Comment: x from 0 to 1 and y from x to x+1.

Comment: It seems your answer is correct...

Comment: i'd guess that the computer is interpreting (e^30 - 1) as (e^29)... try more parentheses? or (-1 + e^30)?

Comment: it says the answers are equivalent, but it seems as though this should be the correct answer according to you and the other person who answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=x}^{x+1} e^{30x} dy \right) dx = \int_{x=0}^1 e^{30x}  dx = {1 \over 30} (e^{30} -1)$.

Comment: This is the same answer I got. I think it is the computer that will not accept this correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since copper.hat evaluate the integral exactly, this post should be hint.

You should draw the area to determine from where x and y begins and end, also that would be more practical if you want to evaluate the integral in polar coordinate 
Image from 
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%2C%20y%3Dx%2B1%20from%20x%3D0%20to%20x%3D1):
[image]

However in your question it determines explicitly that